# I got this error while building a blockchain (building a local blockchain)

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node, substrate-front-end, blockchain, block

[image: when i run node template with --ws external its giving me error like this as shown in image below.]
when i run node template without --ws external its producing blocks but when i run with --ws external its giving me error please help me fix this im new to substrate.

Answer (score 0):

The `--ws-external` got renamed to `--rpc-external`. Anyway, for a local node you probably will not need it.
The flag is only needed when you want to run a node and make it accessible externally over a network.

Comment: yes i want to access it externally over a network so im using --ws external but its giving me error